# how to encrypt post data via form submission in ssl for cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.1

I am using cakephp 2.X version. i try to implement login with ssl encryption. But when i click submit button, the post data does not via ssl.

try to follow security component solution:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/security-component.html

However, when post request is not via HTTPS, it will be redirect to https get request. so that i cannot login properly.

I manually change my login form action to

```
<form action="https://localhost/users/login">
```

i works. but is there any better solution?

Answer (score 0):

Your solution would indeed work, you can add an extra layer of security by requiring SSL with the Security component by adding this in your Users controller:

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    $this->Security->requireSecure('login');
}
```

Additionally you can force any non-SSL requests to automatically redirect to an SSL one, by using a `blackHoleCallback` method, like this:

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    $this->Security->blackHoleCallback = 'forceSSL';
    $this->Security->requireSecure();
}

public function forceSSL() {
    $this->redirect('https://' . env('SERVER_NAME') . $this->here);
}
```

If SSL is important for your entire application (e.g. if you're dealing with sensitive data), the best solution would be to have your web server (Apache/nginx/whatever you use) to force SSL on all requests and redirect any non-SSL ones to their SSL alternative.

Comment: thank you for your reply! i did follow this solution. but i try to submit form by POST data, not GET. this solution will redirect my POST request to GET...so that i cannot login properly any idea?

Comment: OKEY. maybe security component only works for htmlHelper. Do i need to create a form via htmlHelper. this one may works. let me try! thank you again!